# Not able to access application hosted on Linux VM on Azure cloud

Tags: linux, azure

I have created a CentOS 7.1 VM using Resource Manager deployment model.

I am not able to access the application using a browser on a machine connected to internet.

However I am able to access the application on same machine and other VM on same virtual network using private IP address.

I configured Network Security Group and allowed port 80 and 443 in Inbound Rules.

Comment: Did you open firewall rules on the vm?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turned out that I needed to open ports under "Inbound Security Rules" and needed to open all in "Source Port Range". For doing so, i needed to put * there and in Destination port for https - 443 etc.

This * thing was the catch which i was missing in all the Inbound security rules for allowing the ports.